# Comodo Positive SSL Trust Logo appearing behind bootstrap div elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have followed this guide https://trustlogo.com/install/ and installed the Comodo Positive SSL trust logo.

I am using bootstrap on my site the seal is placed in the footer.

When you hover over the seal, the pop-up window appears to be under the div element like this (tested on latest chrome):

[image]

Is there a CSS fix to make the pop-up window the top most element? I can't seem to be able to find the element to fix it using `z-index`.

This is my html footer:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5>Information</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://domain.com/about_us">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://domain.com/another_link">Another link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h5>SSL Secured Shopping</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                        TrustLogo("https://domain.com/image/comodo_secure_100x85_transp.png", "CL1", "none");
                        </script>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because one of your elements, most probably `<footer>` has css: `overflow:hidden;`

Remove that from your css and your popover will show.

[Here is more about css "overflow"](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)